# HTML select elements don't respond to mouse clicks in SSL iframe using IE7/WinXP

Tags: html, iframe, ssl, internet-explorer-7

We have a third-party external web page on another domain that we're loading in an iframe, and we've found that in IE7 none of the select drop-downs in the iframe page react to mouse clicks. The drop-downs seem to populate okay, but if we click on the drop-downs they become highlighted but the options box doesn't drop down. Once highlighted the options can be changed using the mouse wheel or with the keyboard arrow keys. Other HTML form and other elements also work fine. We've reproduced this on Windows XP SP3, but we're not sure if it's tied to that operating system.

Both sites are SSL, and there are no security warnings showing up. It seems as if there's some div or other element on a higher z-index interfering with the iframe page interaction, but we can't find anything. The interaction also works fine when the page is loaded from the same domain without SSL, running inside a non-SSL test page in our development environment. So it seems likely to be a problem specifically related to SSL and/or the fact that the contents of the iframe are coming from a different domain.

This also works fine in all the other major browsers we've tested in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same problem over here. Seems to be a problem with the KB2586448 update 
http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;2628724

Comment: Thanks for this - I looked everywhere and couldn't find any documentation. There doesn't seem to be a good workaround, so I'll accept this as the answer. For now we're including additional instructions on the page for IE7 users. Also as a side note - this update was released the exact same day as our new release that included this feature, which explains why it all passed QA before the release but failed after. That one really baffled us.

Answer (score 2):

A fix is now being pushed out on Windows Update:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2618444

> FIX: Some drop-down lists and combo boxes do not appear in Internet
>   Explorer 7 after you install security update 2586448

So hopefully we should soon be able to remove all the fixes and warnings.